# Pinpoint persistance on multiple google map layouts in android

Tags: android-intent

I place a pinpoint on google map layout in android and when i navigate to the second layout and come back, the pinpoint disappears

This is my customPinpount class.

```
public class CustomPinpoint extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {


    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> pinpoints = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    private Context c;

    public CustomPinpoint(Drawable arg0) {
        super(boundCenter(arg0));

    }

    public CustomPinpoint(Drawable m, Context context ) {
        this(m);
        c = context; 

    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return pinpoints.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return pinpoints.size();
    }

    public void insertPinpoint(OverlayItem item){
        pinpoints.add(item);
        this.populate();
    }

}
```

This is my main activity.

```
public class Main extends MapActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_CHOOSE_ADDRESS = 0;
    private MapView map;
    private Touchy t;
    private List<Overlay> overlayList;
    private long start;
    private long stop;
    private MyLocationOverlay compass;
    private MapController controller;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private GeoPoint touchedPoint;
    private Drawable d;
    private Button pinPoint;
    private EditText lat;
    private EditText lon;
    private boolean touched;
    private Button dataInter;
    private Calculate myRadius; 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setUpView();

    }


    public void calculateRadiusClicked(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CalculateRadius.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CHOOSE_ADDRESS);
    }


    private void setUpView() {
        touched = false;
        map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.themap);
        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        t = new Touchy();
        overlayList = map.getOverlays();
        overlayList.add(t);
        compass = new MyLocationOverlay(Main.this, map);
        //overlayList.add(compass);
        pinPoint = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        dataInter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        lat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editlatitude);
        lon = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editLongitude);
        d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_pinpoint);
        myRadius = new Calculate();


        pinPoint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawPinPoint();

            }
        });


    }

    public void drawPinPoint() {

        String a = lat.getText().toString();
        String b = lon.getText().toString();

        if (!a.equals("") && !b.equals("") && touched == true) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this);
            builder.setMessage("Either click on the map or enter the latitude and longitude \nNot both at the same time");
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setNegativeButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();

                        }
                    });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        } else {

            if (a.equals("") && b.equals("") && touched == false) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this);
                builder.setMessage("Enter latitude and longitude or click on the map");
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setNegativeButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();

                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }

            else if ((!a.equals("") || !b.equals("")) && touched == false) {

                int xx = Integer.parseInt(a);
                int yy = Integer.parseInt(b);
                touchedPoint = new GeoPoint(xx, yy);
                OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(touchedPoint,
                        "What's up", "2nd String");

                CustomPinpoint custom = new CustomPinpoint(d, Main.this);
                custom.insertPinpoint(overlayItem);
                overlayList.add(custom);
                controller = map.getController();

                controller.animateTo(touchedPoint);
                map.invalidate();
                //controller.setZoom(6);

            } else if ((a.equals("") || b.equals("")) && touched == true) {

                OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(touchedPoint,
                        "What's up", "2nd String");
                CustomPinpoint custom = new CustomPinpoint(d, Main.this);
                custom.insertPinpoint(overlayItem);
                overlayList.add(custom);
                controller = map.getController();
                controller.animateTo(touchedPoint);
                //controller.setZoom(6);

            }
            if (!a.equals("") && !b.equals("") && touched == true) {
                touched = false;
            }
        }
        touched = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        compass.disableCompass();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        compass.enableCompass();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    class Touchy extends Overlay {

        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e, MapView m) {

            if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                start = e.getEventTime();
                touched = true;
                x = (int) e.getX();
                y = (int) e.getY();
                touchedPoint = map.getProjection().fromPixels(x, y);

            }
            if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                stop = e.getEventTime();
            }

            return false;
        }       
    }
}
```

This is my second activity
    public class CalculateRadius extends Activity {
        private Button calculateButton;
        private EditText transmit_power_dbm;
        private EditText sencitivityEdit;
        private EditText TXEdit;
        private EditText RXEdit;
        private EditText frequencyEdit;
        private RadioGroup radioGroup; 
        public Calculate cal = new Calculate();
        private EditText cellRadius;
        private static final int REQUEST_CHOOSE_ADDRESS = 0;
        private Main main;

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculate_radius);
        setUpView();

    }

    private void setUpView() {
        calculateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        //main = new Main();

        transmit_power_dbm = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTxPower);
        sencitivityEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editRxSensitivity);
        TXEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxHeight);
        RXEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editRxHeight);

        frequencyEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editFrequency);
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

        cellRadius = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditResult);


        calculateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pathLoss();

            }


        });
    }

    public void plotTheRadius(View view){

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CHOOSE_ADDRESS);
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: welcome to SO! Please try to limit your code to that which is in the context of your application only. (ie. no import statements)